# How can I get VSCode's LaTeX Workshop to find the right installation of TeX?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I've installed TeX Live and Visual Studio Code with the LaTeX Workshop extension. Previously, I'd installed LyX. VSCode is looking at the LyX installation. I know this because I had an error complaining it couldn't find a library and it listed the LyX install directory. When I copied the folder from TeX Live to LyX's directory, that error went away. The problem is, I would prefer to use TeX Live. It already has packages I need installed. How can I get VSCode and the LaTeX extension to look at the TeX Live directory? I've looked at the settings and don't see anything that sets that path.

EDIT: I've tried following the information on James Wu's page but I am new to LaTeX and not succeeding. Note that I'm trying to follow instructions given [here to format a poem](https://www.dschapman.com/articles/typesetting-poems-with-latex-i/). I am using the example from that article for my test.

My recipe is:

```
[  {
"name": "latexmk ",
"tools": [
  "latexmk"
]   },  {     "name": "latexmk",
"command": "latexmk",
"args": [
  "-synctex=1",
  "-interaction=nonstopmode",
  "-file-line-error",
  "-pdf",
  "-outdir=%OUTDIR%",
  "%DOC%"
],
"env": {"TEXMFHOME": "c:/texlive/2019"}   } ]
```

The errors I am getting are:

```
Latexmk: This is Latexmk, John Collins, 26 Dec. 2019, version: 4.67.
Latexmk: Changing directory to 'c:/Users/tuata/OneDrive/Documents/'
Rule 'pdflatex': The following rules & subrules became out-of-date:
      'pdflatex'
------------ Run number 1 of rule 'pdflatex'
------------
------------ Running 'pdflatex  --max-print-line=10000 -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode -file-line-error -recorder -output-directory="c:/Users/tuata/OneDrive/Documents"  "texsample.tex"'
------------ Latexmk: applying rule 'pdflatex'... This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.19 (MiKTeX 2.9.6630) entering extended
mode (c:/Users/tuata/OneDrive/Documents/texsample.tex LaTeX2e
<2017-04-15> Babel <3.18> and hyphenation patterns for 75 language(s)
loaded.

c:/Users/tuata/OneDrive/Documents/texsample.tex:1: LaTeX Error:
There's no line here to end.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation. Type  H
<return>  for immediate help

c:/Users/tuata/OneDrive/Documents/texsample.tex:1: LaTeX Error:
Missing \begin{document}.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation. Type  H
<return>  for immediate help

Overfull \hbox (20.0pt too wide) in paragraph at lines 1--5 [] 

c:/Users/tuata/OneDrive/Documents/texsample.tex:6: LaTeX Error:
There's no line here to end.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation. Type  H
<return>  for immediate help

c:/Users/tuata/OneDrive/Documents/texsample.tex:6: LaTeX Error:
Missing \begin{document}.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation. Type  H
<return>  for immediate help

Overfull \hbox (20.0pt too wide) in paragraph at lines 6--26 [] 

c:/Users/tuata/OneDrive/Documents/texsample.tex:27: LaTeX Error:
There's no line here to end.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation. Type  H
<return>  for immediate help

c:/Users/tuata/OneDrive/Documents/texsample.tex:27: LaTeX Error:
Missing \begin{document}.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation. Type  H
<return>  for immediate help ) ! Emergency stop !  ==> Fatal error
occurred, no output PDF file produced! Transcript written on
c:/Users\tuata\OneDrive\Documents\texsample.log. Latexmk: Summary of
warnings from last run of (pdf)latex:   =====Latex reported missing or
unavailable character(s).
=====See log file for details. Collected error summary (may duplicate other messages):   pdflatex: Command for 'pdflatex' gave return code 1
      Refer to 'c:/Users/tuata/OneDrive/Documents/texsample.log' for details Latexmk: Undoing directory change
=== TeX engine is 'pdfTeX' Latexmk: Errors, so I did not complete making targets Latexmk: Use the -f option to force complete
processing,  unless error was exceeding maximum runs, or warnings
treated as errors.
```

Here is the sample code I am using:

```
\\poemtitle{Pied Beauty}
\\begin{poem}
\\begin{stanza}
G\\textsc{lory} be to God for dappled things--- \\verseline
\\verseindent For skies of couple-colour as a brinded cow; \\verseline
\\verseindent\\verseindent For rose-moles all in stipple upon trout that swim;\\verseline
Fresh-firecoal chestnut-falls; finches’ wings;\\verseline
\\verseindent Landscape plotted and pieced—fold, fallow, and plough;\\verseline
\\verseindent\\verseindent And all trades, their gear and tackle and trim.\\verseline
\\end{stanza}
\\begin{stanza}
All things counter, original, spare, strange;\\verseline
\\verseindent Whatever is fickle, freckled (who knows how?)\\verseline
\\verseindent\\verseindent With swift, slow; sweet, sour; adazzle, dim;\\verseline
He fathers-forth whose beauty is past change:\\verseline
\\versephantom{He fathers-}Praise him.
\\end{stanza}
\\end{poem}
```

Comment: Have a look here: https://github.com/James-Yu/LaTeX-Workshop/wiki/Install#setting-path-environment-variable

Comment: I've tried doing what I think this is telling me, but I'm failing miserably. I'm going to edit my question to include more info.

Comment: Please post the code you used. And: are you using  single or double backslashes, i.e. `\\documentclass{article}` or `\documentclass{article}`?

Comment: @DG' I added the code. I'm using double backslashes.

Comment: Ok. That's wrong! Don't do it. Something went **horribly** wrong with article you linked. DON'T USE DOUBLE BACKSLASHES.

Comment: Ohhhhh! Okay that's kind of vital information. I'll change that up when I get home and see what happens. Thanks! @DG'

Comment: @DG' I got rid of the double backslashes and did some other cleanup that became clear after that. I'm now getting an "Undefined control sequence" error for each line that begins with one of the \verseindent tags. I'm going to go do more research on that poemscol package and other poetry-related packages.

Comment: This has wandered away from my original question. I've figured that out, so I will post that as an answer. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 4):

I figured out how to change the path. In VSCode, click on Extensions (the icon with the 4 boxes). Then select LaTeX Workshop and click on Settings. Scroll down to Latex Workshop -> Latex: Tools. Click on "Edit Settings in Json" and type in the following:

```
[
  {
    "name": "latexmk",
    "tools": [
      "latexmk"
    ]
  },
  {
    "name": "latexmk",
    "command": "latexmk",
    "args": [
      "-synctex=1",
      "-interaction=nonstopmode",
      "-file-line-error",
      "-pdf",
      "-outdir=%OUTDIR%",
      "%DOC%"
    ],
    "env": {"TEXMFHOME": "c:/texlive/2019"}
  }
]
```

Set your TEXFMHOME path as needed. Save. This should get you the installation you want.

Comment: I just found the existing latexmk blurb and added the path that shows up under `which latex' to its env, and now it works!