# Priority set for latex manager in VSCode to read sty files

Tags: latexmk, vscode

I am kind of new with Visual studio code, the basics that I have understood so far is that path definition, environment setup and installation on host machine is important.

Regarding the use of .sty files in latex manager, I am bit unsure of the priority set of reading files from different directories. There are three possibilities:

1. sty files and modified `moderncv` in the same directory as .tex file
2. sty files and modified `moderncv` in `/home/user/texmf/tex/latex/local` directory
3. latex manager read it from texlive installation on host machine `/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/moderncv/moderncviconssymbols.sty`

As far as I have understood, option (1) here has the priority, then (2) and then (3), could someone please confirm that?

Now, here is my main issue, I got my copy of `moderncv.cls`, which I copied to both location (1) as well as (2), however latex manager keep sending me following error message [A], since its reading the `moderncv` from the location (3).

For `Latex Manager`, I installed `texlive` on host machine (Ubuntu  22.04) by following this [B], section for `tl;dr: Unix(ish)` and set the `PATH` in `.profile` as

```
## For VSCode to read the path of the texLive
export PATH="/usr/local/texlive/2023/bin/x86_64-linux:$PATH"
export TEXMFHOME="/home/user/texmf"
```

The `settings.json` of Latex Manager project is here [C], though I defined `.env` variable, did not bring any change.

I have already did enough google without any success. There was this page on stackexchange [D], however did not take me any further. If someone could point me to the right direction, would be great.
If more information is needed, please do let me know.

Thanks,

### [A]

```
[{
    "resource": "/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/moderncv/moderncviconsawesome.sty",
    "owner": "LaTeX",
    "severity": 8,
    **"message": "Command \\xingsocialsymbol undefined.\n",**
    "source": "LaTeX",
    "startLineNumber": 37,
    "startColumn": 1,
    "endLineNumber": 37,
    "endColumn": 65536
},{
    "resource": "/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/moderncv/moderncviconsawesome.sty",
    "owner": "LaTeX",
    "severity": 8,
    **"message": "Command \\gitlabsocialsymbol undefined.\n",**
    "source": "LaTeX",
    "startLineNumber": 40,
    "startColumn": 1,
    "endLineNumber": 40,
    "endColumn": 65536
},{
    "resource": "/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/moderncv/moderncviconsawesome.sty",
    "owner": "LaTeX",
    "severity": 8,
    **"message": "Command \\stackoverflowsocialsymbol undefined.\n",**
    "source": "LaTeX",
    "startLineNumber": 41,
    "startColumn": 1,
    "endLineNumber": 41,
    "endColumn": 65536
},{
    "resource": "/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/moderncv/moderncviconsawesome.sty",
    "owner": "LaTeX",
    "severity": 8,
    **"message": "Command \\bitbucketsocialsymbol undefined.\n",**
    "source": "LaTeX",
    "startLineNumber": 42,
    "startColumn": 1,
    "endLineNumber": 42,
    "endColumn": 65536
},{
    "resource": "/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/moderncv/moderncviconsawesome.sty",
    "owner": "LaTeX",
    "severity": 8,
    **"message": "Command \\skypesocialsymbol undefined.\n",**
    "source": "LaTeX",
    "startLineNumber": 43,
    "startColumn": 1,
    "endLineNumber": 43,
    "endColumn": 65536
},{
    "resource": "/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/moderncv/moderncviconsawesome.sty",
    "owner": "LaTeX",
    "severity": 8,
    **"message": "Command \\orcidsocialsymbol undefined.\n",**
    "source": "LaTeX",
    "startLineNumber": 44,
    "startColumn": 1,
    "endLineNumber": 44,
    "endColumn": 65536
},{
    "resource": "/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/moderncv/moderncviconsawesome.sty",
    "owner": "LaTeX",
    "severity": 8,
    **"message": "Command \\researchgatesocialsymbol undefined.\n",**
    "source": "LaTeX",
    "startLineNumber": 45,
    "startColumn": 1,
    "endLineNumber": 45,
    "endColumn": 65536
},{
    "resource": "/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/moderncv/moderncviconsawesome.sty",
    "owner": "LaTeX",
    "severity": 8,
    **"message": "Command \\telegramsocialsymbol undefined.\n",**
    "source": "LaTeX",
    "startLineNumber": 48,
    "startColumn": 1,
    "endLineNumber": 48,
    "endColumn": 65536
},{
    "resource": "/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/moderncv/moderncviconsawesome.sty",
    "owner": "LaTeX",
    "severity": 8,
    **"message": "Command \\whatsappsocialsymbol undefined.\n",**
    "source": "LaTeX",
    "startLineNumber": 49,
    "startColumn": 1,
    "endLineNumber": 49,
    "endColumn": 65536
},{
    "resource": "/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/moderncv/moderncviconsawesome.sty",
    "owner": "LaTeX",
    "severity": 8,
    **"message": "Command \\bornsymbol undefined.\n",**
    "source": "LaTeX",
    "startLineNumber": 52,
    "startColumn": 1,
    "endLineNumber": 52,
    "endColumn": 65536
}]--------------------
```

[B] https://www.tug.org/texlive/quickinstall.html

### [C]

```
{
   /* "workbench.colorTheme": "Noctis",*/
    "editor.fontFamily": "'Droid Sans Fallback', 'Droid Sans Mono', 'monospace', monospace",
    "editor.fontSize": 14,
    "files.autoSave": "afterDelay",
    "files.autoSaveDelay": 5000,
    "latex-workshop.view.pdf.viewer": "tab",
    "latex-workshop.latex.outDir": "Pdf",
    "latex-workshop.latex.tools": [
        {
            "name": "latexmk",
            "command": "latexmk",
            "args": [
                "-synctex=1",
                "-interaction=nonstopmode",
                "-file-line-error",
                "-pdf",
                "-aux-directory=%TMPDIR%",
                "-output-directory=%OUTDIR%",
                "%DOC%"
            ],
            "env": {"TEXMFHOME": "/home/user/texmf/"}
        },
        {
            "name": "pdflatex",
            "command": "pdflatex",
            "args": [
                "--shell-escape", // if you want to have the shell-escape flag
                "-synctex=1",
                "-interaction=nonstopmode",
                "-file-line-error",
                //"-aux-directory=test",
                "-output-directory=Misc",
                "%DOC%"
            ],
            "env": {"TEXMFHOME": "/home/user/texmf/"}
        }
    ],
    "latex-workshop.latex.recipes": [
        {
            "name": "latexmk",
            "tools": [
                "latexmk"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

[D] [How can I get VSCode's LaTeX Workshop to find the right installation of TeX?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/526320/how-can-i-get-vscodes-latex-workshop-to-find-the-right-installation-of-tex?newreg=41471709146c4450a256e0be9da3abce)

Comment: What exactly do you have in the local directory?  If it is only a modified `moderncv.cls`, then the additional files that `moderncv` uses (there are quite a lot) will still be sourced from the central `/usr/local/texlive/2023/` distro.

Comment: Yes, it is the modified moderncv.cls in both place 1 as well as 2. I used to use texmaker before to building etc, and for that I used to integrate modified moderncv. It used to compile w/o any such error warnings, since it used to read my modified moderncv. Now, with new laptop, I thought of using VSCode and that's where my learning curve lies.. Still the question lies, what is the priority set for VSCode to read files?  Why it is ignoring the files kept at 1 as well as 2. ??

Comment: The error is coming not from `moderncv.cls`, but `moderncviconsawesome.sty`, which `moderncv.cls` loads (`moderncv` is split up into a number of files of which `moderncv.cls` is just the entry point), if a `moderncviconsawesome.sty` is not in the local directory then the file is being correctly be sourced from `/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/moderncv/moderncviconsawesome.sty`.